# Intermittent nginx timeouts with no error logged when connecting from Google Apps Script

Tags: nginx, google-apps-script

I've got an nginx + php-fpm server that I call from a Google Apps Script. From time to time I see an exception "Address unavailable" in Google Apps Script.

I can't find any errors logged in the nginx error.log file that correspond with this (although there are other things in error.log for the site so the log file is correctly configured).

The site itself is hosted on Google Cloud Platform, so it seems odd that there would be a network connectivity problem, and the error shown by GAS is different if there is a DNS lookup issue (I tested by putting in a domain that doesn't exist).

Any ideas about how to debug this? My goal is to find out if I can avoid these errors by increasing the maximum number of connections or changing some other configuration on the server to improve performance, but I don't want to just start making random changes without more information about what the underlying cause is.

Comment: Is the error intermittant? Does it connect on retry successfully or does it continue to error? If it errors, how long before you can connect back again?

Comment: Yes the error is intermittent, even other requests made around the same time work fine, so it's not continuously throwing the same exception. It seems like it's a capacity problem, like lots of requests at once and some of them time out. The same requests work later when retried.